# Couldn't install Spring Tool Suite could not be installed for eclipse Luna

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, spring-boot, spring-tool-suite

I want to use spring boot and could not install STS 4.0 in eclipse Luna IDE.
I tried updating from preferences but one common error persists for STS 4.0. 
The error says

```
session context was:(profile=epp.package.java, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.workspace,1.5.1.v20120328-0001No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.wikitext,3.0.37.20200303191522No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.wikitext.markdown,3.0.37.20200303191522
```

I think the problem lies with the eclipse version but how to know which version of eclipse is compatible with latest STS. and if I could externally download dependencies than how to do it.

Comment: You want the current release: 2020-03. Luna is from 2014.

Answer (score -1):

You can download the latest Spring Tools 4 for Eclipse distribution from https://spring.io/tools. It contains the latest Eclipse release (2020-03 at the moment) with Spring Tools 4 pre-installed.

If you would like to install the Spring Tools 4 into an existing Eclipse installation, you can find instructions on the wiki: https://github.com/spring-projects/sts4/wiki/Installation

For the latest Spring Tools 4 release you would need to least Eclipse 2019-12 (since we ship an update site for each release that is compatible with the previous Eclipse release). But I would highly recommend to use the latest available release and the ready-to-use distribution from https://spring.io/tools.